# MVC display records on view from controller without Viewbag/Viewdata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

New to mvc, I have a controller like this

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime Date, DateTime DDate)
{
DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
 ViewBag.b = dt;

 return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DateTime Date, DateTime DDate)
{

List<myCollection> myCollectionList = new List<myCollection>();

// Fill the list

 return View();
}
```

Now, what I want to do is pass the myCollectionList to view (Razor cshtml) for displaying the collection records

Edited: myCollection class is in controller

```
public class myCollection
{
            public string date { get; set; }
            public string ddate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear (to me) where you have a problem. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @M4N thanks, it worked well, i was doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly. You can simply return the myCollectionList from the action:

```
return View(myCollectionList);
```

The access it from the View using the Model property:

```
@model IList<myCollection>

...

@foreach (var obj in Model) {
  <li>@obj.Property</li>
}
```

See also [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx).